# Yahoo GeoPlanet & XPathNavigator C#

Tags: c#, web-services, xpath, yahoo

I am returning XML data from the Yahoo GeoPlanet web service using `HttpWebRequest`.

I am loading the XML using

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
```

Next comes:

```
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
```

If I do `nav.Select("places");` or `nav.Select("/places");` or `nav.Select("//places");`, nothing gets returned!

But if I do `nav.select("/*");`, I get the node and doing `node.Name` returns `places`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about the format of the Yahoo data but I do know that the most common misstake with C# and XPath is forgetting to add the relevant namespaces to your "NamespaceManager" have a look here http://mydotnet.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/worlds-smallest-xml-xpath-tutorial/

Comment: Worked a charm once the NameSpaceManager was added. Thanks